# explorer.exe, windows 10 slow login with one user

Tags: performance, windows-explorer, windows-10, user-profiles, login-screen

I have 3 users on my computer using Windows 10. One of them recently became slow to login (6 seconds instead of 2). I looked in event viewer and both users have the same history when loging in. It seems that the winlogon is slower with one user (slow when showing "welcome").

Is that possible to profile what winlogon is trying to do? Are there more specific logs I can check? Thank you.

edits:
It looks like the problem is caused in part by explorer.exe (thank you  magicandre1981) since when I change the shell to something else, the problem is no present. I tried to disable some explore.exe extensions but not all of them. Maybe I should try to disable all shell extensions. I will also try with explorer.exe from an older Windows version (if there's no security against that).

I tried autoruns too and both users (slow and fast) have the same config. When I disable everything, the problem is still present.

This is not a domain-joined user nor a roaming profile. It's a just a regular local profile.

I only experience the slow login on that user when it's the first user to log in after boot. If I log with another user, then I logout and login with the slow login user, the issue is not present.

Comment: I normally use Autoruns to disable everything that is automatically started to determine what is causing performance problems like this.

Comment: Thank you but I tried autoruns too and both users (slow and fast) have the same config. When I disable everything, the problem is still present.

Comment: Install the Windows 10 SDK/WPT (https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), login to an admin account, run the xperf commands from this link: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10128.tools-for-troubleshooting-slow-boots-and-slow-logons-sbsl.aspx#Using_XPERF_to_capture_slow_logons. Compress the **merged.etl** as 7z/RAR, upload it and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I assume this isn't a domain-joined machine. If it is, do you use roaming profiles and if so, have you checked how big the user profile is?

Comment: No, this is not a domain-joined user nor a roaming profile. It's a just a regular local profile. Thank you magicandre1981, it helped a lot. I installed WPT and by comparing the ETL of the good and bad user, I discovered that explorer.exe was part of the problem. If I change my shell from explorer.exe to something else (cmd or taskmgr), the problem is not present. I will try to disable some shell extensions using shellexview to see if the extensions are the problem.

Comment: have you figured out which extension was the cause?

Comment: Not yet. I have disabled many extensions but not all of them yet.

Comment: Now the issue is absent. It happened before. It looks like an intermittent problem.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) or [Windows Performance Toolkit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/). Compare the events which are logged among the following login scenarios:

- Normal login
- Safe mode login
- Sign out then login again
- Wake from sleep

Disable things which slow down the login process such as:

- Network Discovery (under manage advanced sharing settings)
- Pinning to Quick Access
- Unnecessary services (Bluetooth, Virtual Machines, Emulators, etc)
- Internet Access (Turn on Airplane mode on the lock screen)

And scripts such as:

- Startup (under task manager)
- Use setup script (under network proxy settings)

**References**

- [The Case of the Veeerrry Slow Logons – Mark's Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2012/07/01/the-case-of-the-veeerrry-slow-logons/)
- [windows - Slow Network Discovery - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/440808/slow-network-discovery)
- [Devices not working before log on a computer running Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057300/devices-not-working-before-log-on-a-computer-running-windows-10)
- [Tip of the Day: An easy way to measure computer reboot and logon times – Tip of the Day](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tip_of_the_day/2017/08/15/15855/)
- [Slow Initial Login When Using Folder Redirection](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX133595/)